# Magento: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100002112' for key 2

Tags: database, magento

Hey I'm a complete magento noob, but we upgraded our version to the latest and now when you finish checking out and finish payment, you are presented with this error.

I've truncated the log tables like everyone seems to suggest, I've checked for duplicate skus. I've looked into reindexing our product prices as it says it needs to be reindexed, but when I do, i'm presented with this: 'There was a problem with reindexing process.'.

Here's the error from the checkout. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

There has been an error processing your request
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100002112' for key

Comment: Try increasing the increment_last_id in the table eav_entity_store.Make sure that the value is greater than the increment id of currently existing orders.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the index for the invoices in the end. You have really saved my bacon! I wish you had answered so I could upvote you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try increasing the increment_last_id in the table eav_entity_store.Make sure that the value is greater than the increment id of currently existing orders.

Comment: This is correct,  but you don't want to arbitrarily set a number, you want to check the last order / invoice / shipment ID that was used in the admin and set it to that. This will prevent this from happening again if an order happened to get created in between the value you set and the last actual order value..  This typically works great in smaller stores, but can be a pain on stores that take extensive orders and you can hurt a few transactions in the process.