# Magento mysql table drop before import - safe?

Tags: mysql, magento, ssh, import

We recently updated our Magento 1.7.0.2 CE Instance to 1.9.1.0.

Now we want to import all tables considering cms pages, blocks, catalog categories, products, email templates.

While importing them via SSH we stumbled over an error: 1062 Duplicate entry on checkout '1-1'

I tried to edit the tables and inserted SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; but it did not help.

TRUNCATE via SSH did not help either.

Can I drop the tables and import them immediately afterwards? Will it help? Or will it crash magento completely?

I want to edit following tables:

cms_block cms_block_store cms_page cms_page_store core_email_template downloadable_sample downloadable_sample_link downloadable_product downloadable_product_price downloadable_product_link downloadable_product_purchased

and all of the catalogue tables.

Comment: Hi Dimi,Please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270777/magento-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-100002112-for-ke

Comment: Thanks mate. I will try and inform if it helped.

Comment: or should i correct the export method of the tables and export them one more time? like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278470/phpmyadmin-error-1062-duplicate-entry-1-for-key-1

Comment: Yes, you can do that also If you don't have time issue. Please approve my comments if its helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your hint mate. I will try it tonight. We dont have the time issue, as we are not live already and migrating in the dev environment.

Comment: Its my pleasure if this code helps you. Checkout my new gig
https://www.fiverr.com/mohitverma836/make-an-ecommerce-website-for-you?arrived_from_manage_gigs=true&display_share=true